# Install NodejS application Globally

Tags: node.js, npm

It's really easy to install a Node module from NPM with:

```
sudo npm install -g ModuleName
```

But how about doing the same from a Node application code that is on the same machine?
How can it be installed globally? I want to be able to execute it without entering the full path and without publishing it to NPM.

Comment: go into your module's directory and do `sudo npm install -g` and it will install your module globally (assuming you have the proper package.json including the `bin` directive)

Comment: [npm link](https://npmjs.org/doc/link.html) can help you

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks Chad, that's correct. I can just go inside the application and run sudo npm install -g.

Comment: you shouldn't copy chad's comment, add it as your own answer and then accept it. better would have been to ask chad to make his comment an answer and then accept it.

Comment: haha brilliant 